# Verical space between flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two flex items in a container wrapped in a column, and there it is a big space between the the two boxes, I tried to use `align-items: flex-start;` or `align-self: flex-start;` but does not work.

please look at the code snippet.

thank you.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  }
.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  }
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-basis: 100px; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    max-width: 100px;
}
.sidebar > div {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">

  <div class="sidebar">

    <div></div>
    <div></div>

  </div>

  <div class = "content">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have given height of 50px to each flex-item. How do you expect the behaviour my friend. To being them one below the other I guess? If I have understood your question correctly

Comment: align-content not align-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `flex-direction: column;` to the `.sidebar`

```css
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-basis: 280px; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 280px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.sidebar > div {
    background: blue;
    width: 280px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 1px; /* Demo purposes */
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">

<div></div>
<div></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe I have already answered it. hehe !!!
Anyways, Cheers !!!

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Yeah. I saw your answer after posting mine. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `flex-direction:column;` to get them one below the other.

If this is what you are looking for :)
Also for your information, `flex-basis` is the property of `flex-items` and not of `flex-container`.

```css
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
       height: 400px;
       flex-direction:column;
       max-width: 280px;
}
.sidebar > div {
    background: blue;
    width: 280px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">

    <div></div>
    <div></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

no need to wrap your `flexbox` of `.sidebar` just simply comment it out. and add `flex-direction: column;`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  }
.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  }
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /* flex-basis: 100px; */
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    align-items: flex-start;
    max-width: 100px;
}
.sidebar > div {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">

      <div class="sidebar">

        <div></div>
        <div></div>

      </div>

      <div class = "content">

      </div>

    </div>
```